# How to setup JsonSerializerSettings for an ASPNET.Core application?

Tags: .net, json, asp.net-core

ASP.NET Core has the following two extension methods to help setting up some default JSON settings, for your app:

```
- services..AddJsonOptions(options => options.SerializerSettings) // SS is a GETTER only.
- services.AddJsonFormatters(options => 
  {
      options.NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore; // etc.
  }
```

Both ways only allow you to *manually* specify each property to set.

How can I pass in an instance of a `JsonSerializerSettings` to use. The idea here is that I don't know what the settings are .. just use this instance which has various settings defined.

e.g.

```
var myJsonSerializerSettings = SomeHelper.CommonJsonSerializerSettings;
services.AddJson(myJsonSerializerSettings);
```

Comment: Hmm, not sure if the API allows that at the moment. AddJsonOptions uses services.Configure(action) internally, and within MvcJsonOptions it uses [JsonSerializerSettingsProvider](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/f4ff537a312ed46ab01470e70a6bab2133260f55/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.Json/JsonSerializerSettingsProvider.cs) to get the default implementation. Static class ftw.